# html5 nav or menu?

Tags: html, menu, nav, semantic-markup

I know this was asked and discussed before, but this is a hybrid scenario (not at all uncommon, though).

There's this (fixed) toolbar above the page, that contains a mix of navigation and actions - such as: link to home-page, dropdown of pages, dropdown of categories, search box, subscribe form, rss link, contact-form launcher, facebook like button, scroll-to-top arrow (javascript). Which it the better wrapper for the toolbar, `<nav>` or `<menu>`?

Comment: You do know that `menu` is not part of [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/)? (but [`menu`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/semantics.html#the-menu-element) is part of the current Draft of HTML 5.1)

Comment: Does this mean that it souldn't be used yet?

Comment: Not if you want to use W3C’s HTML5. You could decide to use W3C’s HTML 5.1, but as it’s a still only a Working Draft, many things might change over time and you might have to update your markup, if you care about it. WHATWG’s HTML also specifies the [`menu`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-menu-element) element, but it’s a Living Standard, so you have to decide if you want to commit to this.